# .htaccess allow one url to be accessed either via HTTPS or HTTP

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a rewrite rule in `.htaccess` that redirects our site to HTTPS

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I need to leave one url open to work both HTTP and HTTPS (`http://www.myhost.com/api` and `https://www.myhost.com/api`). How do I need to modify my above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/support/registration_service
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Above rule excluding the uri `/api` to be forced to https so you can use `www.myhost.com/api` for both scheme.

Comment: I get `Internal Server Error` with that additional rule

Comment: Ok now the error is gone, but it's still redirecting to HTTPS automatically. My actual url is actually `http://www.myhost.com/support/registration_service` not `api`. Maybe it's got something to do with this... I have changed `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^api` to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^support/registration_service `

Comment: In which directory you are using the .htaccess?

Comment: In the root directory

Comment: Still automatically redirecting from http -> https

Comment: Mmmhhh Strange, similar conditions are working for me you don't have any other conflicting rule?

Comment: my bad, think it is working correctly... I am doing some additional tests to be sure.